How to prove? $\sum_{k=r}^{2n-1}k2^k{2n-k-1\choose n-1}=n2^r{2n-r\choose n}$
How do I prove the following identity?
$$\sum_{k=r}^{2n-1}k2^k{2n-k-1\choose n-1}=n2^r{2n-r\choose n},$$
where $r$ and $n$ are integers satisfying $0\le r<2n$.
The motivation is that this identity arises when counting the number of one-dimensional symmetric random walks on $\mathbf Z$. In particular, ${1\over2^{2n-r}}{2n-r\choose n}=\sum_{k=r}^{2n-1}{k\over2n-k}{2n-k\choose n}2^{k-2n}$ gives the probability that a one-dimensional symmetric random walk on $\mathbf Z$ with $2n$ steps returns to the origin exactly $r$ times; the summand indexed by $k$ gives the probability that the $k$th return occurs at step $2n$. The setup is laborious, so for details I refer interested readers to problem 10.10 in chapter III of William Feller, An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications volume 1, third edition (1968).
Using a computer, I’ve checked this up to $n=100$.
Apologies if this has already been asked or is contained in a well-known reference. In any case, I would be happy to learn of any references or similar identities.

induction downwards on $r$ should work easily. Have you tried that?

Or this?

@CalvinLin Wow, I just did that and got it easily as you said. Feeling silly now. Thanks for your help!

@J.G. I did try that but I wasn't able to figure it out

We follow the idea Calvin Lin gave in the comments to fix $n$ and induct downwards on $r$. When $r=2n-1$, the identity reduces to $0=0$. Suppose now that the identity holds for $r$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=r-1}^{2n-1}k2^k{2n-k-1\choose n-1}
&=n2^r{2n-r\choose n}+(r-1)2^{r-1}{2n-r\choose n-1}\\
&=n2^{r-1}\biggl(2{2n-r\choose n}+{r-1\over n}{2n-r\choose n-1}\biggr).
\end{align*}$$
We wish to show that this is equal to $n2^{r-1}{2n-r+1\choose n}$. It suffices by the addition formula to show that
$${2n-r\choose n-1}={2n-r\choose n}+{r-1\over n}{2n-r\choose n-1}.$$
Multiplying both sides by $n!$, we wish to show that
$$n(2n-r)_{n-1}=(2n-r)_n+(r-1)(2n-r)_{n-1},$$
where $(a)_k=a(a-1)\dots(a-k+1)$ denotes the falling factorial. But this is clear after subtracting the rightmost term from both sides.

As an aside, $ { 2n - r +  1 \choose n } = \frac{ 2n-r + 1 } { n } { 2n - r \choose n-1 }$ makes the arithmetic immediate.
